# sorting using qsort in c

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

i have this code in c

```
const char * array[] = {
    "1",
    "2",
    "helloworld",
    "worldhello",
    "3",
    "zzzzzzzzzz",
    "Zzzzzzzzzz",
    "zzzzzzzzzZ",

};

/* n_array is the number of elements in the array. */

#define n_array sizeof(array)/sizeof(const char *)

/* Compare the strings. */

static int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    /* The pointers point to offsets into "array", so we need to
       dereference them to get at the strings. */

    return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}

int main ()
{
    int i;
    qsort (array, n_array, sizeof (const char *), compare);
    for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        printf ("%d: %s.\n", i, array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i want the output become like this

```
helloworld
worldhello
Zzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzZ
```

how i modified my code to get the output

Comment: I love your `i < 50000` in the for loop. Got any meaningful output? By the way, you still have the strings "1", "2" and "3" so you can never get your desired output.

Comment: Just print each of those in turn, and you're done. Or perhaps edit your question so that it is meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'Z' is smaller than 'h', it will be sorted as first.

You can of course use `stricmp` (or `strcmpi`) but now the strings with a Z or z in them will be sorted in an arbitrary order.

Then there are the strings "1", "2", "3" and you can't remove them (actually you can, but not with sorting).

So your wish cannot be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs:

a) to much dereferencing pointers in `compare`, it's actually much simpler:

```
static int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
    return strcmp (a, b);
}
```

b) your output loop, going to 50000, seriously?

```
    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        printf ("%d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }
```

Getting rid of "1", "2", "3" is another exercise.